# Why does the post_type_link hook everything twice?

Tags: php, functions, hooks

I've added a Wordpress hook:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_link_venue', 11, 3);
```

Everything in that hook prints twice. I've simplified it to its minimum.

```
function custom_post_type_link_venue ($urlsub2, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
      echo "test";
    }     
}
```

When I fire that function, "test" is shown twice.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a filter to `post_type_link`, you are telling WordPress to run the hooked function on the result of the [`get_post_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) function. So any time that function runs, so does yours.

When I tested the filter myself, I only saw a printed message once for each link, but if you have something like this:

```
if ( get_permalink() ) {
    the_permalink();
}
```

Then you will see a message printed twice. This is because `get_permalink()` calls `get_post_permalink()` internally, and so does `the_permalink()`. Your `custom_post_type_link_venue()` function will run each time.

Since `post_type_link` is a filter, not an action, it should only `return` a value, and *not* output anything. If your function does produce any output you may get unexpected results, like you are experiencing.

Comment: The echo was only for testing purpose, because I saw that the return also returns it twice.

Comment: Well yes, of course it does, for the same reasons.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this? Or is there an error somewhere?

Comment: It makes no sense to bypass it. I don't think you've understood my answer. What would you even be bypassing? What problem is this even causing?